# How to use replace statements with JQuery but exclude one class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search engine. When you are directed to the next page, the keywords in the search bar are highlighted on the page. However, there is a particular link that I don't want highlighted. The highlighter is messing up the links url, so I get a link like: `<a href='page.php?url=ha<mark>ppy</mark>'</a> ha<mark>ppy</mark></a>`

This is the code I'm using:

```
function term(word) {
    var src_str = $("#page").html();
var term = word;
term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

$("#page").html(src_str);
}
```

I want the code to have the same replace functionality, but not replace `.topic_link`

**EDIT**

The problem is not only with `.topic_link`. The code affects all the *html* of the page. So, if I searched "div", all the outside HTML code would be affected. Is there a way to only affect the text of the document and not the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you'll have to traverse through children and check their [node types](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/nodeType).
Since every child can have other children, recursion must be applied:

```
function changeText(word,element) {   
  $.each(element.contents(),function(){
    if(this.nodeType == 1)
      changeText(word,$(this));
    else if(this.nodeType == 3)
    {
      $(this).replaceWith(term(word,$(this).text()));
    }
  });

}

function term(word,src_str) {

  var term = word;
  term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
  var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");

  src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
  src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

  return src_str;
}
```

Now call:

```
changeText("YourWord",$("#page"));
```

This has been tested on small amount od data, so I don't know if it'll be efficient enough.

Comment: Brillant. Thank You!